# angularjs + spring4 rest - upload file with json data

Tags: angularjs, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I'm having a page where employee can fill their details and upload image. I'm sending post request to my spring rest with file and form data as given below:

```
var formData=new FormData();
    formData.append("data", angular.toJson($scope.employee));
    formData.append("file",$scope.file);
    $http.post('rest/employee/upload', formData, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
    .success(function(){
    })
    .error(function(){
    });
```

Below is my spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody EmployeeBean upload(EmployeeBean employeeBeanJson, MultipartFile file) {

}
```

When I send the post request with both image and formdata, image is reaching controller properly but the formdata ie. employeeBean contains fileds with null value.

When I changed controller to:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody EmployeeBean upload(MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("data") String employeeBeanJson) {

}
```

Here formdata is coming as string json with all required values.

I've added multiPartResolver to spring-context:

```
<beans:bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="2097152" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Although I can convert this string json to Object but the problem is that I wont be able to use @Valid and I need to do validation again.

Is there any way to make first spring controller work?
In case I manually convert jsonToObject using Object Mapper, is there a way to invoke @Valid?